# Escanear un texto ingresado por el usuario en R

Tags: r

Hola a todos necesito una ayuda aquí por favor ¿cómo leer o escanear texto ingresado por el usuario r?

```
print("Ingresar nombre")
  Nombre<-scan()
print(Nombre)
```

Lo que quiero hacer es pedir un nombre y guardarlo en una variable para luego imprimir la variable.

Comment: Hola! Trata de incluir en tu pregunta el código en el que trabajas, lo que hiciste para tratar e resolver tu problema y los errores que encontraste

Comment: Me puedes ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

La forma básica es usar la función [`readline()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/readline), por ejemplo:

```
Nombre <- readline(prompt = "Ingresar nombre: ")
print(paste("El nombre ingreado fue: ", Nombre))
```

Importante:

- Si estás trabajando con R Studio, el input (obviamente) se hace sobre la consola de comandos, por lo que deberás darle foco a este panel, para recién completar el input
- El código anterior (el input y la impresión del nombre) no funciona de forma interactiva ya que la forma de ejecución es línea a línea, por consiguiente las dos líneas se ejecutan por separado.

Ahora, con respecto al último punto **¿Cuando sí funcionará?**

1. **Al hacer click en el botón "Source"**: En este caso se ejecuta el código completo del script, en realidad en este caso no estamos ejecutando de forma interactiva.
2. **Al ejecutar únicamente el "input"**: Por ejemplo si solo ejecutamos esta línea:

   ```
   Nombre <- readline(prompt = "Ingresar nombre: ")
   ```

#### 3. Al combinar las dos líneas con el `;`

```
    Nombre <- readline(prompt = "Ingresar nombre: ");print(paste("El nombre ingreado fue:", Nombre))
```